# Could not find .php file in /var/www in apache server

Tags: php, linux, vagrant, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using Vagrant provider for server, now look at my directories :

in my system:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCXIm.png

vagrant-site
-Project(/var/www)
--public (/var/www/html)
---index.php

now I created a sample .php file in Project folder then when I run vagrant and logged in vagrant ssh when I cd to /var/www ,that .php file doesn't exist there and I could not work with

```
include __DIR__ . '/../count.html.php';
```

this line of code not working because this file doesn't exist in /var/www but exist in my system

That index.php file it's work there is no Problem , but I want to create a php file outside of public directory that , just my self can access that , now when I create that file inside Project folder so now this file must be inside /var/www and when I use include command in my php code , php can not found that , I used file_exists() function and gave the path of php file function , now the function returned false then I check /var/www directory to check that php file exist or not , not exist!

Comment: did you check your project folder in /var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

I solved  problem,
in vagrant file in Sync folders config section , I found out I can add more directories so I synced : ./Project to /var/www but remember,
something it will change after sync ,this directory : /var/www/html ,
that html folder inside apache2 it will remove and replaced with your public directory  name (inside your device ,for me it was public )  [public directory folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YgMx.png),
and now you need to change your root directory  address inside 000-default.conf file in this Path: /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf after you change this restart apache2 service

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html change this => /var/www/your public directory name
```

---

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```